# Why doesn't this output "Please try again" when loop runs again?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, io, cout

Hello I am trying to learn c++ and I wanted to give a little practice with a program.  However I'm having trouble using cout within the loop.

This is the loop I'm trying to output text from. When the user enters a number that isn't valid it is supposed to say "Sorry try again!"

```
while (datecheck)
{
    bool check(false);
    if (check)
        std::cout<<"Sorry try again!"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>c;
    if (c >= 1)
    {
        if (b == 2 && c <= 28)
            datecheck = false;
        if (b == 2 && a % 4 == 0 && c <= 29) 
            datecheck = false;
        if (b == 4 || b == 6 || b == 9 || b == 11 && c <= 30) 
            datecheck = false;
        if (c <= 31) 
            datecheck = false;
    }
    check = true;
}
```

When it outputs and I purposely keep myself in the loop it doesn't output anything

```
Year: -20
-20
-20
```

Comment: You set, inside the loop, your flag to false, via initialisation of the local variable. Then if it is true, you output. When do you expect the output?

Comment: Mover the line `bool check(false);` out of while loop. and `check = true;` should be part of else condition.

Comment: Wait I'm dumb.  I guess when it restarts the loop and declares the flag as false.  My bad.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a fresh new variable `check` at *every* iteration. And you initialize that variable to `false` every time. So move that declaration before the while loop.

Change this:

```
while (datecheck)
{
    bool check(false);
    ...
    check = true;
}
```

to this:

```
bool check(false);
while (datecheck)
{
     ...
    check = true;
}
```

Comment: I think it does @MKR at the end of the loop.

Comment: Will I have to re-declare the variable as false if I run a similar loop that does the same thing every time?

Comment: Ok I got that problem with the code solved.  Thanks again!  I have another question about 
another snippet of code.  Should I ask a new question or where should I ask it?

Comment: Good @amgtree. Yes post a new question and share the link with me, if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with declaration of `bool check(false);`. This keeps on re-assigning value to `false` at beginning of each iteration.

A simple fix could be to get-rid of use of `check` variable and use only `datecheck`.

```
bool datecheck(true);
while (true)
{
    std::cin>>c;
    if (c >= 1)
    {
        if (b == 2 && c <= 28)
            datecheck = false;
        if (b == 2 && a % 4 == 0 && c <= 29) 
            datecheck = false;
        if (b == 4 || b == 6 || b == 9 || b == 11 && c <= 30) 
            datecheck = false;
        if (c <= 31) 
            datecheck = false;
    }
    if (datecheck)
    {
        std::cout<<"Sorry try again!"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to add an explanation to your code-only answer? Creating the impression that StackOverflow is a free coding service is not much loved here.